# Is it possible to find the area of a triangle from the length of one side and the measure of the opposite angle?

Tags: euclidean-geometry, problem-solving

Sorry for maybe stupid question, because I'm pretty sure the context is incomplete, but anyway.

Given $$ \triangle ABC; AC = 4 cm; \angle ABC = 45°; S \triangle ABC-? $$

That's all. Is there a way to solve this?

Comment: It is not solvable.

Comment: No. we need the measure of at least one more side or angle.

Comment: By the [Inscribed Angle Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inscribed_angle), there are infinitely-many triangles with a given side and opposite angle; the vertex of the given angle could be anywhere along a particular circular arc. The height (to the given side) ranges from a minimum (of $0$) for a "flat" triangle to a maximum for an isosceles triangle, and thus the same is true for the area. That is to say: the given information does not determine a specific area.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:

[image]

That's right, there in not enough data to find the area of $\triangle ABC$,
however, we can state that it can't be greater
than
\begin{align}
S_{ABC}
&\le
\tfrac14\,|AC|^2\,\cot\tfrac12\angle ABC
.
\end{align}